# Reduce bootstrap 4 card-column spacing

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap column with 8 cards in it, to almost create that "masonry" effect from getbootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-columns) - I only used one online image for the JSFiddle example though, and I removed the card headers etc... My problem is: I want to reduce the spacing (gaps) between the thumbnails, to about 2pixels, but it doesnt seem to be working at all. I tried putting the "classic_thumbnails" style in all the divs, I tried adding p-1 and m-1, nothing seems to working, and as expresssed in the "classic_gallery" style, the corners (border radius) is still rounded, which I would like to be sharp...

The HTML

```
<div class="container"> 

<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
     image">
  </div>
  <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
image">
  </div>
  <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
image">
  </div>
   <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
image">
  </div>
  <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
image">
  </div>
  <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
image">
  </div>
  <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
 image">
  </div>
   <div class="card classic_thumbnails">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/8v9vYpl.png" alt="Card 
image">
  </div>
</div>  

</div>
```

Here is the CSS (the html file does include a link to the Bootstrap CDN as well:

```
.classic_thumbnails {
border-radius: 0px;
margin: 1px;
padding: 1px;
border: 1px;
border-color: #000000;

}
```

Any help would be so appreciated, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JodyTerblanche/4v96p8k1/13/#&togetherjs=PoFRaqJ9xr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the spacing, you must overwrite the CSS for the class `.card-columns`. Below I reduced the spacing from `column-gap: 1.25rem;` to `column-gap: 1.25rem;`

```
.card-columns {
    column-gap: 0.25rem;
}
```

To remove the border radius for sharp corners you need to overwrite `.card-img` to remove the `border-radius`.

Like this:

```
.card-img {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Your class `.classic_thumbnails` is instead adding your CSS to the outer `div`'s wrapping the images.

Your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8q20m1et/

Comment: Perfect, why this Tip is not included into Bootstrap official guides? :)